# Does non-conservation of number of particles imply zero chemical potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, chemical-potential

In the systems like photon gas in a cavity and phonon gas in a solid number of particles is not conserved and chamical potential is zero. Is this a general rule? If yes, how zero chemical potential is obtained from number non-conservation?

Comment: Related : previous [answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/6694/6316)

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/707562/226902 ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6687/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/196286/226902 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60499/226902

Answer (score 13):

The question can be answered most easily by considering a grand canonical ensemble, where the density operator has the form $\rho=Z^{-1}e^{-\beta(H-\mu N)}$, with $\beta=1/kT$ where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant and $Z$ is determined such that the trace is 1.

In equilibrium, the density operator commutes with the Hamiltonian. This is the case iff the exponent commutes with $H$. If the chemical potential $\mu$ is nonzero, this only holds if the number operator $N$ commutes with the Hamiltonian $H$, and hence is conserved.

Therefore non-conservation implies a zero chemical potential.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I didn't catch the reasoning!

Comment: Which argument is unclear?

Comment: Could you please include some formulae?

Comment: @richard: done!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Sorry for commenting on this old post. I found it interesting. One confusion. Isn't [H, N] always nonzero for a grand canonical ensemble because the system is connected to a reservoir?  If $[H, N]\neq 0$ is always true for a GC ensemble, then $\mu=0$ always which is certainly false. What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: @mithusengupta123: [H,N] is always zero for a grand canonical ensemble in equilibrium. This is by definition. Look at examples to see it.

Comment: Isn't $[H,N]=0$ for any free field theory?

Comment: @IvanBurbano: Yes, but in real life matter fields are never free.

Comment: Therefore, for any interacting theory we always have a zero chemical potential?

Comment: I guess I am also confused by the claim that $[H,N]=0$ for a grand canonical ensemble in equilibrium. The statement that $[H,N]=0$ is an operator equation, independent of the state, e.g. the grand canonical ensemble.

Comment: @IvanBurbano: The grand canonical ensemble belongs to a different representation of the field algebra. The commutator equation holds only weakly, hence depends on the sector.

Comment: This sounds really interesting. Kind of thing one would find in Hash’s book maybe? Do you have any reference suggestions for this?

Comment: Would weakly mean that $tr(\rho[H,N]A)=0$ for all operators $A$, where  $\rho$ is the gran canonical ensemble?

Comment: @IvanBurbano: Yes to the second question. I have no simple reference for the first, just generalities about algebraic quantum field theory.

Comment: I just realized Haag autocorrected to Hash in my comment. Sorry.

Comment: Thus, what is the special thing about photons that prohibits the existence of a sector in which $[H,N]=0$? It seems like a naive application of your argument would indicate that for any type of particle $\mu=0$.

Comment: @IvanBurbano: Photons have zero mass, hence even small interactions produce an infinite number of soft photons.

Comment: Ok, so then the conclusion is that for any massless particle $\mu=0$?

Comment: @IvanBurbano: For neutrall massless particles, yes. But for charged particles represented by $U(1)$ invariant complex fields, there is a conservation law, which makes the charge (number of particles  minus number of antiparticles) commute with the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to [vnb](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/34840/vnb)'s answer, recall that $\mu$ is in general nothing but a Lagrange multiplier that constraints the number of particles to a fixed value $N$:
$$
\Lambda=\cdots+\lambda_1\left[N-\sum_i n_i\right]
$$
where $\Lambda$ is a certain theormodynamic potential that we want to minimise.  The equation for $\lambda_1$ fixes
$$
N=\sum_i n_i
$$

By comparing $\Lambda$ to the standard thermodynamic potentails (e.g., the internal energy) we can conclude that $\lambda_1$ is proportional to $\mu$.

Now comes the key point: if we do **not** want to fix $N$, then there is no need to introduce $\lambda_1$ at all, or equivalently, we can freely set $\lambda_1=0$, that is, $\mu=0$. In other words, if the number of particles is not fixed, there is no reason to introduce the chemical potential. No formula can depend on $\mu$, which is equivalent to setting $\mu=0$.

Reference: [The physical meaning of Lagrange multipliers](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0609v1).

Comment: I wish someone has told me $\mu$ is for fixing the number of particles when I first learned stat mech...

Comment: However, $\mu$ fixes only the average number of particles. Even if the exact number of particles is not fixed, is the average ill-defined?

Answer (score 3):

If in your system the number of of photons is non conserved, the Gibbs free energy cannot depend on the number of photons. So you will have

$$\mu_{\gamma}=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_{\gamma}}\right)_{T,P}=0$$

This also implies that $\mu_{matter}+\mu_{\gamma}=\mu_{matter}$. However, in systems that conserve the number of photons, you return to the Bose-Einstein distribution, and have a non zero chemical potential.

Comment: Why can't Gibbs free energy depend on the $N$?

Comment: An alternative reasoning is that $G$ should be minimum w.r.t. $N$, so $\partial G/\partial N = 0$

Answer (score 2):

> Particle number is not fixed(conserved)

think about this picture:

You have a closed equilibrium system: if it is an electron gas, as long as temperature $k_BT \ll m_e c^2 $ , the number of electron is fixed.

However, if $k_BT \gg m_e c^2$, the electrons number is not fixed either, even for a closed fermionic system!  This really contradict with the statement of thie question. But only the other hand, we know, the question statement is correct.

So, the essential thing is not conservation law. It is a matter of energy scale.

---

When $\mu\ll k_BT$, I call the particle number is an **irrelevant thermodynamic parameter**

$$dF=-SdT+PdV-\mu dN-MdH$$

For example:

If a material is very weak in magnetization, $0 \approx M\ll k_BT$, the magnetic field $H$ is called **irrelevant**. 
Then we can set $M=0$, the physics becomes:
$$dF=-SdT+PdV-\mu dN$$

Similarly,

those **collective modes excitation** like photon, phonon, magnon are not ''real'' particles, which require higher energy scale to create.
The particle number is **irrelevant**  for them.

---